# Excel Formula Appling only when data entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that I am looking to have formulas applied *only* after data is entered. Cell formats are dates. What needs to occur is if a date is entered in A1 then A2 would =A1+14days.

Comment: Will `=IF(ISBLANK(A1), , A1+14)` work for you? What you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IF() function to test:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1+14,"")
```